# Error when create a MicroK8s cluster : Connection failed. The hostname (xx) of the joining node does not resolve to the IP "xx". Refusing join (400)

Tags: cluster, microk8s

I have installed microk8s(1.24/stable) on two machines.
The ip of the two machines are：172.29.99.187, 172.29.99.188.
I operate the command at 172.29.99.187：`microk8s add-node`

Output:

```
From the node you wish to join to this cluster, run the following:
microk8s join 172.29.99.187:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916

Use the '--worker' flag to join a node as a worker not running the control plane, eg:
microk8s join 172.29.99.187:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916 --worker

If the node you are adding is not reachable through the default interface you can use one of the following:
microk8s join 172.29.99.187:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
microk8s join 192.168.192.122:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
microk8s join 172.24.0.1:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
microk8s join 172.30.239.1:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
microk8s join 172.17.0.1:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
```

I operate the command at 172.29.99.188：

```
microk8s join 172.29.99.187:25000/57a191d07ce8fe360e13f4f1e9026ce8/5be428d4e916
```

Output:

```
Contacting cluster at 172.29.99.187
Connection failed. The hostname (cxsw) of the joining node does not resolve to the IP "172.29.99.188". Refusing join (400).
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution on github：https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/2967#issuecomment-1059942384

Edit /etc/hosts on the 172.29.99.188 machine,Add:

```
172.29.99.188 cxsw
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the same IP to the control plane node as well

Comment: or hostnames must be somehow resolvable